# Using CSS with google font - all formats?

Tags: html, css, fonts, cross-browser, font-face

I'm using Google's font : [**Roboto**](https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Roboto)

When I download the zip file ( in order to use it localy)  - I get this zip file :

[image]

But in order to use this font [*with older browsers*](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/)  I need this format :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'MyWebFont';
  src: url('webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: url('webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('webfont.svg#svgFontName') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

But as You can see - I don't have the `eot` , `woff` , `svg` formats.

There *are* online tools but they yield different results.

**Question:**

How/Where can I get the most trusted/official formats for my google font ?

Comment: You can use http://www.fontsquirrel.com/ to generate the fonts. The service is straight-forward and genuine.

Comment: @ViswalingaSuryaS it [only has ttf](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/find_fonts?filter%5Blicense%5D%5B0%5D=web&q%5Bterm%5D=roboto&q%5Bsearch_check%5D=Y). ( using roboto search)

Comment: You can upload your fonts in this page http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator and generate all the possible formats :)

Comment: you should be able to include them from google directly like this 
`@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto);` they claim to support IE6+

Comment: @paulitto I need those fonts  to be locally.

Comment: @SalmanA Where do you see those versions ? I just showed you the zip file which i downloaded from google. there are only TTF there

Comment: You should go with Font Squirrel, seriously its best suited for your requirements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option One: http://everythingfonts.com/font-face - Use this to upload your file and it will convert to cross browser @font-face.

Option Two:

First Step ->  https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Roboto

Second Step -> Open Roboto in Google Fonts (top right corner link)

Third Step -> Choose the way you'd like to call the font for your body (follow the steps)
  - Standard
  - @import
  - Javascript

Answer (score 1):

Just three days ago i had the same problem. i solved it like this:

WOFF is supported in FF 3.6+, Chrome 5.0+, Safari 5.1+, IE 9+  so your modern browsers are covered. [as seen on caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/woff)

as far as older browsers (< IE 9) you just need the eot file. you get it by opening the google font css file in a browser in which you can change the useragent. If you change the useragent to ie 7 for example, the stylesheet will include the link to the eot file.

for example if you open this link with useragent ie 7 in chrome: [Roboto Google Font css file](http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,300,500,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,500italic,700italic,900italic,100)

it will output this:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/roboto/v10/5YB-ifwqHP20Yn46l_BDhA.eot);
  src: local('Roboto Regular'), local('Roboto-Regular'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/roboto/v10/5YB-ifwqHP20Yn46l_BDhA.eot) format('embedded-opentype'), url(http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/roboto/v10/2UX7WLTfW3W8TclTUvlFyQ.woff) format('woff');
}
```

so just grab the eot file url from the src:
http://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/roboto/v10/5YB-ifwqHP20Yn46l_BDhA.eot

Comment: This is masterful. :P Funny thing is, I didn't realize that about `EOT` so I was overlooking it while trying to discover a method for him.

Comment: you don't need to do this for all browser versions. you already have the ttf files. ttf is supported in all browser except ie (overview: http://caniuse.com/ttf) for ie you can get the eot file by changing your user agent to any ie version. OR if you work under windows, you can just visit the link via ie and get the eot file.

Comment: What about svg ? And ttf ?

Comment: you don't need svg if you have the ttf files. and as you said, you already have them, don't you? just download the eot files like i explained and you are ready to go.

Comment: @LeaveAirykson - SVG is for older IOS browsers, so you do need it if you want to support those. WOFF is the emerging standard, so it may be a good idea to include that as well, to be forward-compatible. A browser will only ever download one of the formats, so it's no big deal to have them all on your server.

Answer (score 1):

Goto http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

Upload your font file(.ttf) > Choose Expert > Click Agreement > Download Your Kit.

This will create all formats of your uploaded file with font face CSS as a .zip file. Just extract and use the fonts/CSS to yours.

Answer (score 0):

Google says when you download the zip:

> You do not need to download the font to use it on your webpages.
>   Instead, refer to the "Use" section.

[https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Roboto:400,400italic,700,700italic](https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace%3ause/Collection%3aRoboto:400,400italic,700,700italic)

Answer (score 0):

From google: [https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Roboto](https://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace%3ause/Collection%3aRoboto)

Standard inclusion for HTML:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Integrate in your CSS:

```
font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
```

BTW, you may use http://www.fonts.com/web-fonts/google for syncing your desktop with Google Fonts

Answer (score -1):

This is nice trick I dont know it helpful or not for you, But I always do this thing to my projects.. Just go

[Click here](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator)

& upload your fonts on this website & click on convert button this website gives you `eot, svg, woff` files automatically & this site also gives u css code u just copy & paste that code in your `css file` & copy all those file in css folder...
Enjoy....

Comment: FontSquirrel is mentioned most often in contexts like this, but it handles each typeface as a font family, making HML and CSS coding less convenient and less natural. Besides, the question is about getting “the most trusted/official formats”.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela You can rename each with the same font family with custom style and font weight... Font Squirrel is the best option here...